# Why did they build a Hedonismbot?

Tags: futurama, robots

He was supposedly built out of gold with taxpayers money. Now he is wealthy and has his own servant. What was [Hedonismbot](http://futurama.wikia.com/wiki/Hedonismbot)'s original purpose?

Comment: They needed to round out the full spectrum of robotic personalities. ;)

Comment: It was funded by Mitt Romney's Bain Capital in the early 2090s as a grand experiment in social apathy.

Comment: @JohnO You got me to cross check that comment :)

Comment: Thanks @Major Stackings. If any Futurama producers are reading this, I'm available for hire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Infosphere page on Hedonismbot](http://theinfosphere.org/Hedonism_Bot), on the Season 3 commentary Matt Groening remarked

> he is the actual personification of hedonism.

Given that and being created by taxpayer money, he was presumably created as a research project to see what the actual personification of hedonism would look like and, like many research projects, look on a life of its own (pun intended).